# Second Y-Axis in a R plotly graph

Tags: r, graph, plotly, axis-labels

I combined 2 charts and I am trying to add the second y-axis, but every time I add the yaxis = "y2" to my code, I lose have the my bar graphs.

```
>    MediaDate     Spend Search_Visits Other_Visits MediaDate2 
> 2016-04-01 $39654.36         19970         2899   Apr 2016 
> 2016-05-01 $34446.28         14460         2658   May 2016  
> 2016-06-01 $27402.36         12419         2608   Jun 2016
```

my original code is:

```
p <- plot_ly(x= w$MediaDate2,y=w$Search_Visits,name = "Paid Search",
type = "bar")
p2 <- add_trace(p, x=w$MediaDate2, y=w$Other_Visits,name = "Other Traffic",
type = "bar")
spend_visits <- layout(p2, barmode = "stack")
spendvisits2 <- spend_visits %>% add_trace(data=w, x=MediaDate2,  y=round(Spend,0), fill="tonexty", mode="lines",
                       text=w$MediaDate2, hoverinfo='name+y+text', name="Spend")
```

When I add the yaxis= "y2", only the area chart remains:

```
`spendvisits2 <- spend_visits %>% add_trace(data=w, x=MediaDate2,     y=round(Spend,0), yxis="y2" fill="tonexty", mode="lines",
                       text=w$MediaDate2, hoverinfo='name+y+text',  name="Spend")`
```

Any suggestions would be immensely helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See this quick [Plotly tutorial](https://plot.ly/r/multiple-axes/) for multiple axes. You need to specify the attributes for the second y axis in `layout()`.

```
df <- data.frame(MediaDate = as.Date(c("2016-04-01","2016-05-01","2016-06-01"), format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
                 Spend = c(39654, 34446, 27402),
                 Visits = c(19970, 14450, 12419))

plot_ly(df, x = ~MediaDate, y = ~Spend, type = "bar", name = "Spend") %>%
  add_trace(x = ~MediaDate, y = ~Visits, mode = "lines", yaxis = "y2", name = "Visits") %>%
  layout(yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y", side = "right"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, the code worked perfectly! I know that to create an area graph, I would need to add the code [fill="tozeroy"]. However is there a way to overlap the bar graph on the area?

Comment: "'bar' objects don't have these attributes: 'mode'" i am getting this error ,

Comment: could there be a solution that produces the grouped bars that I believe op was asking for?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
plot_ly(df) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~MediaDate, y = ~Spend,type = "bar",  name = "Spend") %>%  
  add_trace(x = ~MediaDate, y = ~Visits, mode = "lines", yaxis = "y2", name = "Visits") %>%
  layout(yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y", side = "right"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding type='scatter' to what Vance Lopez commented worked for me:

```
plot_ly(df, x = ~MediaDate, y = ~Spend, type = "bar", name = "Spend") %>%
    add_trace(x = ~MediaDate, y = ~Visits, type = 'scatter', mode = "lines", yaxis = "y2", name = "Visits") %>%
    layout(yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y", side = "right"))
```